# Issue with grabbing largest values and ID and index field in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a top 10 count grabbing the ID, title and value and I am a little stuck.

This gets the value that I am looking for:

```
=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER('Risk Register Tool'!$R$4:$R$63),'Risk Register Tool'!$R$4:$R$63),F12)
```

However, I am looking to grab field `A4-A63` and `E4-E63` that is associated with that object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

I tried this but it didn't work, it thinks that isn't a formula

```
TOP 10 RISKS            
Risk #  Risk ID Risk Title  RiskExposure
1       123     Test        25
2                           25
```

Edit: I tried the following formula as well:

```
=INDEX('Risk Register Tool'!$A$4:$A$63;MATCH(=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER('Risk Register Tool'!$R$4:$R$63),'Risk Register Tool'!$R$4:$R$63),F12))
```

Comment: I tried =INDEX('Risk Register Tool'!$A$4:$A$63;MATCH(=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER('Risk Register Tool'!$R$4:$R$63),'Risk Register Tool'!$R$4:$R$63),F12))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:**

I understand that you need to retrieve a proper "Risk ID" in order to correctly match info in the remaining columns (I-K). I would suggest doing the following:

This array formula (enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) will retrieve a row number of the next consecutive Risk ID:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(IF(--('Risk Register Tool'!$T$4:$T$25=Summary!G11),ROW('Risk Register Tool'!$T$4:$T$25),1000),COUNTIF($G$11:G11,G11)))
```

Result:

[image]

Now you can either use this formula to create an additional 'helper' column with the row number and use INDEX to retrieve values for each column, e.g.:

```
=INDEX('Risk Register Tool'!$A$1:$A$25,Summary!$L11)
```

[image]

...or you can skip the 'helper' column and add this formula to each column (note - this solution will be slower if you work with a big data set):

Array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=INDEX('Risk Register Tool'!$A$1:$A$25,SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(IF(--('Risk Register Tool'!$T$4:$T$25=Summary!$G11),ROW('Risk Register Tool'!$T$4:$T$25),1000),COUNTIF($G$11:$G11,$G11))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help unfortunately it didn't work.  I created a shared link on dropbox perhaps it would make it easier.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cakx8z9vyqr0osp/AABpwAoUiInhPU56R7IbsQzaa?dl=0

Comment: the issue are it isn't grabbing the right fields in order.  I have to admit this is the hardest thing I did in excel

Comment: Thanks for sharing the file, this is much clearer now. I'll update my answer in a minute.